# Colocar datos en un array sin eliminar los anteriores

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, push

Tengo un array vacío y una función que cada vez que se da clic a un elemento toma un id especifico y lo coloca en un array a través de push, lo que quiero es que cada vez que se haga clic se guarde los elementos anteriores y se introduzcan los nuevos datos en cada clic.
Esto es lo que tengo al momento

```
const dataId = [];

const setData = (idData) => {
    setReload(!reload);
    dataId.push(...dataId, [idData]);
  };
```

La pregunta es, ¿hay alguna manera de que cada vez que se ejecute la función se guarden los datos nuevos sin que se borren los anteriores? Como pueden ver ya he intentado usar spread operator pero no funciona.

Comment: No es relevante, hace un setState y lo envía a otro componente en react.

Comment: Entonces `dataId` debe recordar estos `id's` en ese componente en especifico, después de que el mismo se devuelva.

Comment: El metodo array.push( item) es para agregar un elemento al final del array() y con array.unshift(item) es para agregar un elemento al inicio del array().

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de poder realizar eso sin problema con `push` te muestro un ejemplo practico para que puedas aplicarlo a tu proyecto:

```js
const dataId = [];

const setData = (idData) => {
    //setReload(!reload);
    dataId.push(idData);
  };

//EVENTO A LOS BOTONES PARA OBTENER ID
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(boton=>{
  boton.addEventListener('click',function(){
  //MANDAMOS A LLAMAR TU FUNCION
     setData(this.id);
  //MOSTRAMOS EL ARREGLO
    console.log(dataId);
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="1">BOTON 1</button>
<button id="2">BOTON 2</button>
<button id="3">BOTON 3</button>
<button id="4">BOTON 4</button>
```

NOTA: Si estas trabajando con ReactJS Ponlo en tus etiquetas de la pregunta, para obtener una respuesta lo mas cercana a lo que estas realizando.

Comment: Pues sigue sin funcionar, aún me sigue devolviendo solo un elemento y reiniciándolo cada vez que hago click